# Podio API throwing error while getting Items

Tags: podio

```
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'array_merge(): ...', '/home/forge/mem...', 201, Array)
#1 /home/forge/releases/20180713132954/vendor/podio/podio-php/lib/PodioObject.php(201): array_merge(NULL, Array)
#2 /home/forge/releases/20180713132954/vendor/podio/podio-php/models/PodioItem.php(99): PodioObject::member(Object(PodioResponse))
#3 /home/forge/releases/20180713132954/app/Helpers/PodioBackendHelper.php(243): PodioItem::get(891197897)
```

We are trying to fetch the items using Podio API and we are seeing a lot of errors in logs since last few days. I confirm that we have not changed anything in code since more than a month and also checked Podio PHP library also did not update.

Hopefully, someone from Podio team can check and fix this issue.

Comment: Duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51275045/podio-error-when-getting-apps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Podio error when getting apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51275045/podio-error-when-getting-apps)

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio Yes you are correct but I am not seeing any solution on that item as well. Can you please take a look that why we start getting so many errors randomly.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my thread (which Pavlo kindly linked in his reply) the way to solve this is to wrap the Podio call within a try loop, which is wrapped in a do loop. The do loop executes until the call succeeds, and if the exception is thrown it continues the loop. Very annoying to have to write ~10 lines of code for each Podio call being made (in our system there are probably thousands).